# Find out system defaults for HttpClient timeouts

Tags: java, timeout, apache-httpclient-4.x

How can I find out what the actual timeout values are for HttpClient 4.3? I know how to set them explicitly but I'd like to know which values are used implicitly if I don't overwrite them.

### Example

```
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class HttpClientDefaults
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().build();
        System.out.println("ConnectionRequestTimeout: " + config.getConnectionRequestTimeout());
        System.out.println("ConnectTimeout: " + config.getConnectTimeout());
        System.out.println("SocketTimeout: " + config.getSocketTimeout());
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler()).build();
        HttpParams params = client.getParams();
        System.out.println(params.getParameter("http.socket.timeout"));
    }

}
```

### Output

```
ConnectionRequestTimeout: -1
ConnectTimeout: -1
SocketTimeout: -1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

client.getParams() throws an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException exception. Does somebody know a way to read out the actual values that are going to be used?

Comment: Which line of code threw that exception?

Comment: at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.getParams(InternalHttpClient.java:206)

Comment: I'm using v4.3.2 btw.

Comment: @jansohn did you get an anwser for this ? I'm searching for the same

Comment: @NishanthiWickramasinghe no I did not...

Answer (score 0):

The default value for socket, connect, and connection request timeouts is 0 (no timeout)

Comment: If that were true, I shouldn't experience java.net.SocketTimeoutException, should I? When I connect to a web application I occasionally get those, so I wanted to find out what the default values actually are.

Comment: This is true. Feel free to review the source.